# Mongodb $pull performed to remove ObjectId("... id") from the nested sub array.

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have searched every single corner of the internet trying to solve this issue, though have been unable to so far. I am trying to execute the mongodb $pull function to remove an Object from an array nested inside a Schema. I have successfully managed to remove the ObjectId when I hard code the id as 'ObjectId("5b68c9eec7171bc263660633")'. Though when I pass in a variable to this it doesnt work at all.

```
var ManagerSchema = Schema({
  manager: {
    isIdentified: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    employeeID: [**{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' }**]
  }
});

var EmployeeSchema = Schema({
  ...
});

var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema); // Employee
var Manager = mongoose.model('Manager', ManagerSchema); // Manager
```

I am trying to remove the part in bold above, before I delete the employee from the database:

```
Employee.pre('remove', function (next) {
  var employee = this;

  Manager.update({}, {
    $pull: {
      'manager.employeeID.$': 'ObjectId("5b68c9eec7171bc263660633")' // works
      // though trying to make it dynamic
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': ('\'ObjectId("' + employee._id + '")\'').toString() // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': '\'ObjectId("' + employee._id + '")\'' // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`${employee._id}`) // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employee._id) // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employee._id) // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': new ObjectID(employee._id) // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': employee._id // doesnt work
      // 'manager.employeeID.$': {"_id": employee._id}// doesnt work
    }
  }, {
    multi: true
  }, () => {
    next();
  }
  )
});
```

I have tried so many other things based on all the articles I can find online, though am at a loss as to why the pure text will be removed, however the variable will not.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `\`ObjectId("${employee._id.toHexString()}")\``?

Comment: No need to use `$` positional operator here... Try with simple `$pull: {
      'manager.employeeID': '5b68c9eec7171bc263660633'}`

Comment: `'manager.employeeID': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employee._id)`?

Comment: Omg legends!!! combination of @Akrion and AnthonyWinzlet answered worked a charm! Spent way too long and did way too many combinations. Appreciate your quick replies. Thanks to all of you. This was the line that worked.

'manager.employeeID': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employee._id)

On that note, doesn't the $ in the line meant to resemble the array item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manager.employeeID` is the correct field access since you do not really need the `$` operator since:

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the
>   query results to contain only the first element matching the query
>   document. To specify an array element to update, see the positional $
>   operator for updates.
>
> Use $ in the projection document of the find() method or the findOne()
>   method when you only need one particular array element in selected
>   documents.
>
> See the aggregation operator $filter to return an array with only
>   those elements that match the specified condition.

[More on the $ here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/index.html)

The correct `ObjectID` call is `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(employee._id)` since it is part of the mongoose Types definition as you can [see here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Types).